# Eneloop NiMh batteries not powering 42030 loader

Tags: technic, power-functions

Is it because the batteries are only 1.2V? It works fine with Duracell alkaline batteries.

Comment: Should work in general with the 1.2v batteries, as I see it you would need to use 6 of them, which would put you at 7.2v - philo has tested most motors at 4.5v and 7v and they all run just fine- also the lego li rechargeable pack runs from ~6-8v, so it doesn't seem like it would be a voltage issue. Does it work with no load connected to the motors?

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply -  the battery case module (its the same as the standard 8293 Lego Power Functions Motor set) ie. takes 6 batteries, so yes, the eneloops give out 7.2v rather than the duracells giving 9v.. Nothing happens at all - the little green led on the battery pack case doesn't light up either...

Comment: I use Eneloop batteries in most of my models and they work fine, including in the 42030. So it can work, the problem is specific to something you're doing (or not doing). Have you checked the obvious things - charged batteries, good connections etc?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the manual states you should use 1.5V ones.

There's also a review on lego.com that states there may be a problem with the battery terminals with some makes of batteries. Worth checking.

Comment: thank you.. yes.. the eneloop has slightly different 'proportions' to the duracells.. need to be careful in inserting batteries...